# SOLR - Optimise the relevance of search results

Tags: search, optimization, solr, feedback

I know I'm asking a difficult question but the future belongs to the bold!

**Question:** Does SOLR provides a way to take into account the past search and user actions so that next time the same query is done, the ranking has slightly changed towards what the other users picked?

**Side question:** how to optimise queries so that the length of the result field is closer to the exact query and redundant words are omitted?

### Background:

When a user search for a particular wine (let's say: "chateau latour"), solr always gives wrong results first such as:

1. Château Triniac Côtes du Roussillon Villages Latour Latour de France
2. Château Latour Beerenauslese Brand - Yountville
3. Château Latour Grand Vin - Pauillac
4. Château Latour à Pomerol

### What is should be:

Ideally the 3rd wine should be the first for this query simply because more than 80% people would select this one when they searched those words. People searching for "chateau latour pomerol" would definitely pick the 4th one.

### My understanding of it:

It seems the 1st is ranked well because of the redundancy of "Latour" which is simply wrong. The 2nd has a better rank than 3rd for unknown reasons. The search is done only on the title of these wines, no other field.

Any ideas of how to feed past actions of users on results to SOLR?
Thank you!

*Note: working & programming on boose related subjects is amazing ;)*

Answer (score 2):

> Does SOLR provides a way to take into account the past search and user
>   actions so that next time the same query is done, the ranking has
>   slightly changed towards what the other users picked?

Not out of the box. But what you can do is to register those picks and update documents accordingly (e.g. have a field called `popularity`) on a regular basis. The rest is as easy as [adding a boost](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29).

> how to optimise queries so that the length of the result field is
>   closer to the exact query and redundant words are omitted?

You need to change the similarity algorithm from the [default (TF-IDF)](https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-Artifacts-4.x/javadoc/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) to your custom one.

> When a user search for a particular wine (let's say: "chateau
>   latour"), solr always gives wrong results first such as:
>
> 1. Château Triniac Côtes du Roussillon Villages Latour Latour de France
> 2. Château Latour Beerenauslese Brand - Yountville
> 3. Château Latour Grand Vin - Pauillac
> 4. Vin - Pauillac Château Latour à Pomerol

I don't have Solr working at hand so I [modelled your scenario in Lucene](http://pastebin.com/GL1Yr7WH), using `StandardAnalyzer`. The order I'm getting is sligtly different: in the linked example results are: 4, 1, 2 and 3 (last two have the same score). Which analyzer are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer, it helped me get started with this issue. Will post my finds when I get some results and improvements.

Comment: I was also using a StandardAnalyzer

Comment: You can turn on [query debugging](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debug.explain.structured) which might help to explain the results coming from Solr.

Answer (score 1):

```
how to optimise queries so that the length of the result field is closer to the exact query?
```

Is the `omitNorms` on that field set to true? Can you set `omitNorms=false` and try in what order the results are sorted? (My guess is 4, 3, 2, 1.) See @Mike's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830795/solr-what-are-the-benefits-of-length-normalization-omitnorms-false).