# How solr ranks documents?

Tags: solr

I have indexed my documents text using the following config in solr:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/> -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="desc" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

And a test query

```
desc:Alabama Crimson Tide Toddler Crimson Team Logo Flannel Pajama Pants
```

Returns the first 2 results that look like:

{

```
"id":"_:node1b897e5ffccc354e5da5128066e2e9e4|https://www.crookscountry.com/product/alabama-greatest-hits",
    "name":"Alabama - Greatest Hits",
    "source_entity_index":"prod03",
    "category":"",
    "category_str":"",
    "desc":"Alabama ~ Alabama - Greatest Hits",
    "host":"www.crookscountry.com",
    "url":"https://www.crookscountry.com/product/alabama-greatest-hits",
    "_version_":1652845859059007489},
  {
    "id":"_:noded8c4ca8e98bb12e1132af18c76f277b|https://shop.spreadshirt.com/thatshirtcray/amateur+sketch+shirt-A12174934",
    "name":"Amateur Sketch Shirt | Men's T-Shirt",
    "source_entity_index":"prod03",
    "category":"",
    "category_str":"",
    "desc":"Leprechaun in Alabama amateur sketch.",
    "host":"shop.spreadshirt.com",
    "url":"https://shop.spreadshirt.com/thatshirtcray/amateur+sketch+shirt-A12174934",
    "_version_":1652846254331265025},
```

But the documents I really want to rank high are ranked even after top 100, e.g.:

```
{
        "id":"_:nodec65a89504cb5f3af808caf654ac7cb72|http://shop.rolltide.com/Alabama_Crimson_Tide_Sweatshirts_And_Fleece_Sweaters",
        "host":"shop.rolltide.com",
        "name":"Men's Crimson Alabama Crimson Tide Big Logo Sweater",
        "text":"Show off your team spirit with this Alabama Crimson Tide Big Logo sweater.",
        "_version_":1646377538225700866},
      {
        "id":"_:nodeebc0adb5a11937556ebdf77132fab580|http://shop.foxsports.com/FOX_Alabama_Crimson_Tide_Sweaters_And_Dress_Shirts",
        "host":"shop.foxsports.com",
        "name":"Men's Crimson Alabama Crimson Tide Big Logo Sweater",
        "text":"Show off your team spirit with this Alabama Crimson Tide Big Logo sweater.",
        "_version_":1646383652576165892},
```

I do not quite understand how the default solr ranking works... it seems that it favours short text, even if there is only one overlapping word with the query. Is there anyway I can change this based on my needs?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Be aware that `desc:Alabama Crimson Tide Toddler Crimson Team Logo Flannel Pajama Pants` searches for `Alabama` in `desc`, but the rest of the terms are searched in the default search field. Seeing as the two documents you want higher doesn't even have a `desc` field, it's hard to say exactly why the score is what it is - append `debug=all` to your query to see how each document is scored (i.e. which terms contribute what to the total score). Using the `edismax` handler (`defType=edismax`) with `qf` and explicit field weights usually give you a better result.

Comment: Thank you I am trying Eric's idea but this is new to me... we perhaps I should have picked this up when learning solr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr document ranking relies on [Lucene Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html).

> *it seems that it favours short text, even if there is only one overlapping word with the query*

This behavior is due to the field length normalization. You can set `omitNorms=true` to disable field length normalization (cf. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html#field-default-properties).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830795/solr-what-are-the-benefits-of-length-normalization-omitnorms-false) for a more in-depth explanation.

Alternatively/additionally with (e)dismax parser you may play with the `mm` (aka [MinimumShouldMatch](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter)) parameter to tweak - not the ranking - but how Solr matches documents.